# Different branch for each remote?

Tags: git

I'm very new to GIT and trying to figure out how to setup my Development / Staging / Production workflow.

- Its a small team just two
- We have two remotes - Staging and Production.
- Only I will be pushing to the Production environment.

I've put together a simple diagram of how i would imagine the workflow might work.

My question is, would each remote have its own unique branch?

- production > master
- staging > development

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why put "staging" between you and the contractor? Is there an intended use-case or desired benefit?

Comment: Changes would be shown to the client and OK'd in staging before being push to production.

Comment: Is the production and staging repository required to be two remotes or can they be a single git-repo with two branches where the contractor is only allowed to push to staging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each git repository (be it remote or not) has its own branches.
2. Branches from remotes can be tracked with local branches.

Having said that: You can create two tracking branches in your local, that track branches on Production and Staging. The names of the branches on Production and Staging do not matter (i.e. they can be the same), as in your repository, they will be prefixed with the remote name.

However, it might be less confusing to to have a global branch naming convention and enforce correct change flow with permissions. I.e. by not letting the contractor push to Production and you on your side, not merging Staging with Production (or not pushing), until you desire to do so.

Comment: ok, maybe tracking is what i need to read up about. WPengine sets up the Production / Staging environments with both branches named master.  this is what confused me. So i can track any local branch to my Staging master, even if the branch names don't correspond..

Comment: @Cam Yes. For example you could have local branch `staging` that tracks `remotes/staging/master` and equally a branch `production` that tracks `remotes/production/master`. Just some nitpicking about terminology: Your local branch tracks a remote branch, not vice versa.

Comment: thanks gzm0, that makes things clearer.. this link reflects your comments - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments